# Error while converting date to timestamp in python

Tags: python

I am currently trying to convert a date in the following format YYYYmmddHHMMSS to a unix timestamp but I get an error (ValueError: year is out of range).

```
import datetime

def ts(date):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    date = 20130814100000
    print ts(date)
```

Comment: Why did you delete your SSCCE? Also, can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: There was a big mistake in the SSCCE, it was a TS to DATE example, while I am asking for a DATE to TS function... My mistake. I am flagging the post to suppress it. Sorry.

Comment: You should be able to delete it yourself and rewrite it.

Answer (score 5):

Your date should be a string. Here is how you do it. (If your date is an integer then just do `date = str(date)`.

```
>>> import time
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date = '20130814100000'
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
>>> print dt
2013-08-14 10:00:00
>>> print time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
1376467200.0
```

`time` also has a `strptime` function but it returns a not so useful `struct_time` object. But if you only need a unix time, then you can use it too:

```
>>> time.mktime(time.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
1376467200.0
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem here is that `.fromtimestamp()` is expecting a Unix timestamp, not a date formatted as YYYYmmdd...

To parse the date information that you do have there, I'd recommend using `.strptime()` or the excellent `python-dateutil` package.

```
import datetime

def ts(date):
    stamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    return stamp.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

or

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

def ts(date):
    stamp = parse(date)
    return stamp.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

http://labix.org/python-dateutil

Answer (score 2):

- The function that **parses** datetime is called [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), not [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) (which formats time).
- 20130814100000 is **not** an [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)
- strptime takes string as argument

Overall, your code should look like:

```
import datetime

def ts(date):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    date = "20130814100000"
    print ts(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some confusion over the different ways that times are represented. The value you have assigned to `date` appears to already be a formatted timestring of "2013-08-14 10:00:00", but you're passing it into `fromtimestamp`. This function expects a Unix timestamp, which is simply the number of seconds that have elapsed since Midnight on Jan 1st 1970.

I believe something like this is what you're looking for:

```
import datetime

def ts(datestr):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    date = 20130814100000
    print ts(date)
```

`strftime` like you had is for *formatting* times into strings. `strptime` is for *parsing* strings into times.